# Record type field is not present in UI

Tags: error, page-layout, record-type

Scenario is I want Communication Attribute field present in record type but field is already present in record type detail page but when i insert record via UI in record type field is not present.I have checked page layout assignment where contact layout is assigned to my profile and in that contact layout Communication Attribute field is not present.

So are page layout and record types linked?
how can i make the field available in record Type UI

Comment: Have you checked the FLS? (Field Level Security). Even if the layout is chosen correctly, it will not show fields that the user doesn't have access to.

All of this is assuming you are not using Dynamic Forms (lightning only), in which case the assigned layout is ignored for field-rendering.

Comment: yes i have checked the FLS and field is editable

Comment: Do you have 'Enhanced Profile User Interface' enabled/disabled under 'User Management Settings'?

Comment: Yes, It is enabled

Comment: Can you check (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326130&type=1&mode=1) steps mentioned

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve this kindly check if the following steps were being followed :-

After the creation of the new field

1. check if FLS is given for that field
2. Check if the field is being added to the pagelayout of particular record type
3. check if the user has access to create the record type's record.